# 530 Permission Denied when trying to log onto FTP

Tags: permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I recently installed VSFTPD and added a user with the following commands:

```
useradd -G ftpusers -d /var/www someuser
passwd someuser
```

I also added `someuser` to `user_list` and confirmed that it does not exist in `ftpusers`. When I try to log in using FireFTP I get a 530 Permission Denied error. `vsftpd.conf` has been set to `anonymous_enable=NO` but when it was set to `YES`, I was able to successfully log in anonymously.

Am I missing something? Should I be setting ownership of `/var/www` or something else?

EDIT: I've tried taking `root` off of `ftpusers` but even when attempting to sign in with `root` I get a permission denied error. This would lead me to believe there's something wrong with my vsftpd or server configuration and not the way the user is set up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I set up an FTP server in Ubuntu using something like this guide and mine works well:

http://cviorel.easyblog.ro/2009/03/05/how-to-setup-vsftpd-ftp-on-ubuntu-linux

Does anything here help?

On another note, you should not change the owner of /var/www.  As long as your group `ftpusers` has access to to it and vsftpd is running as a user that is a member of the group you should be fine.

Comment: Ah-hah! Got it! At the end of that article it indicated that I needed to reset the vsftpd service using: `/etc/init.d/vsftpd restart` Thanks so much! This has taken me forever to figure out.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: Link appears obsolete...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and i solved by removing `userlist_deny=NO` in the `user_list.conf` file and add the same line in  `vsftpd.conf` file, then restart the service with `service vsftpd restart`. I had centos 8 installed

Answer (score 0):

`someuser` requires read (and presumably write) access to `/var/www`

Which permissions does it currently have?

To see permissions, type `ls -l /var` at the command prompt and look at the left hand columns of the file listing.  This gives you your file permissions and the user and group that owns the directories/files.

Read this first if you are at all unsure: [Understanding Linux File Permissions](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions)

Comment: Noob question - how do I check/set permissions?

Comment: I've added some more information to the answer.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. root is the user and group that owns the directories/files. Do I need to be logged in as the user I want to check permissions for? Either way, whether I'm logged in as root or someuser, permissions show that read and write access are available. I don't think that's the issue as I'm able to access that directory as someuser via ssh. Using FTP is a different story.

Comment: Correction - root has full access while someuser has read and execute access. No write access. Would this prevent me from logging in via ftp?

Comment: Shouldn't do - unless your FTP client is attempting to upload something as part of its login routine (unlikely).  If you can access the folder as someuser over ssh, then it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by removing the line **userlist_deny=NO** in the /etc/vsftpd.conf file then restart the service **sudo service vsftpd restart**